# Getting values outside the subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to use some values to shown in graphs, but when I got out the subscribe function the value returned is undefined

I already tried to put in an array of objects and still think this is the right way to do it, but again, when the function go out the subscribe, the values disapear.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getActiveVulForYear(2019);
    console.log(this.vulYearCount); // Here, all the values are printed correctly
    console.log(this.vulYearCount[1]);// Here, the value printed is undefined
}

getActiveVulForYear(year) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
      this.activeVulnerabilitiesByMonth(i, year)
    }
}

activeVulnerabilitiesByMonth(month, year) {
    return this.scanvulService.getScanvuls().pipe(
      map((reports: Scanvul[]) =>
        reports.filter(r => {
          this.arrayVulMonth = new Array()
          this.arrayVulMonth = r.data.split('-')
          return this.arrayVulMonth[1] == month && this.arrayVulMonth[0] == year
        }))).subscribe(
          vulsForYear => {
            this.vulsForYear = vulsForYear
            this.vulYearCount[month] = this.vulsForYear.length;            
          }
    );
}
```

At some point I did an array of objects with two parameters: `month` and `count`.
When I tried to print the count, for some reason the parameters are 0. But when I print the full array, the prints shown all the parameters correctly (with the right `count` and `month`)

Does someone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the console output when you console.log(this.vulYearCount)?

Comment: I agree that you should show the full console output.

With what information is currently available my only suggestion would be that this.vulYearCount[1] truly *is* undefined. Have you verified that this is truly an array that can be accessed by numerical index 'this.vulYearCount[1]' and does this actually that mean 'January' in this context? The current month is July, so I would think this.vulYearCount[7] would be defined if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are executed asynchronously so if you want to do something when they emit a value or complete (e.g. log emitted values) you have to do it in the `subscribe` function. A function that returns an Observable returns immediately and not when the Observable emits a value. You should also subscribe late instead of early. Work with Observables as long as you can and only subscribe when you actually need values from the Observable, i.e. in `ngOnInit` where you want to log the results.

So `activeVulnerabilitiesByMonth` and `getActiveVulForYear` should return Observables. Subscribe to `getActiveVulForYear` in `ngOnInit` and log or set global variables that you want to bind to in the template in the `subscribe` function.

`getActiveVulForYear` also currently leads to `this.scanvulService.getScanvuls()` being called 12 times. If one call to `this.scanvulService.getScanvuls()` returns all data and you only want to filter or rearange the returned data, just fetch the data once and then `filter` or `map` it accordingly.

I think this is what your code should look like:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  getActiveVulForYear(2019).subscribe(vulsForYear => {
    this.vulsForYear = vulsForYear;
    this.vulYearCount = vulsForYear.map(vulsForMonth => vulsForMonth.length);
    console.log(this.vulYearCount);
    console.log(this.vulYearCount[1]);
  })
}

getActiveVulForYear(year: number): Observable<Scanvul[][]> {
  return this.scanvulService.getScanvuls().pipe(
    map((reports: Scanvul[]) => {
      let vulsForYear: Scanvul[][] = Array.from({length: 12}, (v, i) => []);
      reports.forEach(r => {
        let yearMonth = r.data.split('-');
        if (yearMonth[0] == year) {
          vulsForYear[yearMonth[1]].push(r);
        }
      })
      return vulsForYear;
    })
  );
}

getActiveVulnerabilitiesByMonth(month: number, year: number): Observable<Scanvul[]> {
  return this.getActiveVulForYear(year).pipe(map(vulsForYear => vulsForYear[month]));
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bvksfn

Comment: This have solutioned exactly what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you say that

```
console.log(this.vulYearCount); // Here, all the values are printed correctly
```

actually vulYearCount should be empty at that point.

the array vulYearCount gets fullfilled later, when your scanvulService.getScanvuls() pulls the data and passes it to the pipe where you fullfill array.